# Angular route to return text/json and not resolve to a component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am new to Angular, have been having a great time with it.

I would to know how to have a specific URL return only the "text" (body) I want it to return, and not resolve to the router and go through the Angular response creation.

This is specifically with respect to creating the *apple-app-site-association* file which needs to reside at

```
domain.com/apple-app-site-association
```

And the response of the URL should be something like:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For my use case, I am ok with any solution as the specified URL returns what I want (without changing the URL). I am open to:

- Route to overwrite the layout, and render open the component.html file. I can place the contents in there (doesn't seem like an elegant solution though)
- Explicitly mark this URL to a file existing in the code base
- Have the route resolution to look for files in the root directory (or some other directly)
- Any other elegant solution :)

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this use case for some server side routing? and depends on what server side technology you are using, if using [express js](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) you may handle different routes easily to serve either a static content or you can use [angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) for creating your page on server side and achieve what you are looking for, Cheers!!

Comment: You are right :) Don't know why I didn't think of the web framework which passes it on the Angular. Thanks! Shall put it in my express app